# Not able to run python pipeline through airflow BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I'm not able to run  python pipeline through airflow `BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator`. Below is my complete code:

**DAG FILE**

```
    import os
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataflow import DataflowConfiguration
    from airflow.providers.apache.beam.operators.beam import BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator
    from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataflow import DataflowTemplatedJobStartOperator
    
       
    
    default_args = {
        "owner": "<...>",
        "start_date": days_ago(1),
        'dataflow_default_options': {
        "project": "<...>",
        }
    }
    
    dag = DAG(
        dag_id="word_count",
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval="@once"
    )
    
    start_python_pipeline_dataflow_runner = BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator(
        task_id="start_python_pipeline_dataflow_runner",
        runner="DataflowRunner",
        py_file="gs://<...>/word_count.py",
        pipeline_options={
            'input':"gs://<...>/kinglear.txt",
            'output':"gs://<...>/output.txt",
            'temp_location':"gs://<...>/temp/",
            'staging_location':"gs://<...>/temp/",
        },
        py_options=[],
        py_requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]==2.26.0'],
        py_interpreter='python3',
        py_system_site_packages=False,
        dataflow_config=DataflowConfiguration(
            job_name='{{task.task_id}}', project_id="<...>", location="us-central1"
        ),
        dag=dag,
    )
```

**Python File (word_count.py)**

```
    """A word-counting workflow."""
    
    # pytype: skip-file
    
    import argparse
    import logging
    import re
    
    import apache_beam as beam
    from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
    from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
    from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
    
    
    class WordExtractingDoFn(beam.DoFn):
      """Parse each line of input text into words."""
      def process(self, element):
        """Returns an iterator over the words of this element.
    
        The element is a line of text.  If the line is blank, note that, too.
    
        Args:
          element: the element being processed
    
        Returns:
          The processed element.
        """
        return re.findall(r'[\w\']+', element, re.UNICODE)
    
    
    def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
      """Main entry point; defines and runs the wordcount pipeline."""
      parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
      parser.add_argument(
          '--input',
          dest='input',
          default='gs://<...>/kinglear.txt',
          help='Input file to process.')
      parser.add_argument(
          '--output',
          dest='output',
          default='gs://<...>/output.txt',
          help='Output file to write results to.')
    
      argv = [
        '--project=<...>',
        '--region=us-central1',  
        '--runner=DataflowRunner',
        '--staging_location=gs://<...>/temp/',
        '--temp_location=gs://<...>/temp/',
        '--template_location=gs://<...>/templates/word_count_template'
      ]
      
      known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    
      # We use the save_main_session option because one or more DoFn's in this
      # workflow rely on global context (e.g., a module imported at module level).
      pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
      pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
    
      # The pipeline will be run on exiting the with block.
      with beam.Pipeline(argv=argv,options=pipeline_options) as p:
    
        # Read the text file[pattern] into a PCollection.
        lines = p | 'Read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)
    
        counts = (
            lines
            | 'Split' >> (beam.ParDo(WordExtractingDoFn()).with_output_types(str))
            | 'PairWIthOne' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
            | 'GroupAndSum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum))
    
        # Format the counts into a PCollection of strings.
        def format_result(word, count):
          return '%s: %d' % (word, count)
    
        output = counts | 'Format' >> beam.MapTuple(format_result)
    
        # Write the output using a "Write" transform that has side effects.
        # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned
        output | 'Write' >> WriteToText(known_args.output)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
      run()
```

Below is the screenshot of the composer:

[image: Below is the screenshot of the composer]

I am not able to see the dataflow job in the console, as well as count, result in the bucket. Could anyone suggest to me the right approach or any suggestions on this?

Comment: First, please remove all [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_data) in the question please.

Could you please give me more details about your architecture ? Are you triggering the dag from the airflow console or GCP composer console ? Are you processing those data in a dataflow instance on the same project ?

Comment: I have a python script which contains dataflow code to read file from gcs and count the words Appiarance in the file, I am trying to run that script through the airflow BeamRunPythonPipelineOperator which suppose to create a dataflow job for my file/data processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You DAG is ok, the problem is on the **Beam Python file**, there is an error when you send the Dataflow args in the `argv`. The best approach is `extend` `pipeline_args`. And the job is not being submitted because you are sending the `argv` in the `beam.Pipeline`.

Following is the fixed code:

**word_count.py :**

```py
"""A word-counting workflow."""

# pytype: skip-file

import argparse
import logging
import re
import os

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText
from apache_beam.io import WriteToText
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions


class WordExtractingDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  """Parse each line of input text into words."""
  def process(self, element):
    """Returns an iterator over the words of this element.
    The element is a line of text.  If the line is blank, note that, too.
    Args:
      element: the element being processed
    Returns:
      The processed element.
    """
    return re.findall(r'[\w\']+', element, re.UNICODE)


def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
  """Main entry point; defines and runs the wordcount pipeline."""
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument(
      '--input',
      dest='input',
      default='gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt',
      help='Input file to process.')
  parser.add_argument(
      '--output',
      dest='output',
      default='gs://<bucket>/newoutput',
      help='Output file to write results to.')

  #argv = [
  #      '--project=<...>',
  #      '--region=us-central1',  
  #      '--runner=DataflowRunner',
  #      '--staging_location=gs://<...>/temp/',
  #      '--temp_location=gs://<...>/temp/',
  #      '--template_location=gs://<...>/templates/word_count_template'
  #    ]

  known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

  pipeline_args.extend([

      '--runner=DataflowRunner',
      '--project=<project-name>',
      '--region=<region>',
      '--staging_location=gs://<bucket>/',
      '--temp_location=gs://<bucket>/temp',
      '--job_name=your-wordcount-job',
  ])

  
  # We use the save_main_session option because one or more DoFn's in this
  # workflow rely on global context (e.g., a module imported at module level).
  pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
  pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session

  # The pipeline will be run on exiting the with block.
  with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    lines = p | 'Read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)
    
    counts = (
        lines
        | 'Split' >> (beam.ParDo(WordExtractingDoFn()).with_output_types(str))
        | 'PairWIthOne' >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x, 1))
        | 'GroupAndSum' >> beam.CombinePerKey(sum))
    
        # Format the counts into a PCollection of strings.
    def format_result(word, count):
      return '%s: %d' % (word, count)
    
    output = counts | 'Format' >> beam.MapTuple(format_result)
    
    # Write the output using a "Write" transform that has side effects.
    # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned
    output | 'Write' >> WriteToText(known_args.output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  run()
```